# Trying to download h5py, could not build wheels

Tags: python, path, h5py

I am trying to download the h5py package on windows. I am trying to install it with the pip command using a git bash terminal.

I have made sure to have python and some other things to my PATH/Environment Variables. I tried redownloading vscode, and python, tried to update pip and some other commands from this link: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-failed-building-wheel-for-h5py . I was able to succesfully download h5py on my mac, I was wondering if anyone could explain the difference too.

```
  Loading library to get build settings and version: hdf5.dll
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects